how to run concurrent task with asyncio when task is common function
I have two tasks, I want to run them with asyncio concurrently (not in a thread).
But if the tasks are a common function, they will be run one by one. I'm having a hard time making the function async.
I see many samples about asyncio that use the asyncio.sleep function but without tasks.
import asyncio
from time import time
import requests

async def real_task():
    try:
        print(f"{int(time())} : enter to real task")
        requests.get("http://10.65.10.183",timeout=5)   
        # it is no_route server, so it will timeout after 5, that is, this line code will block 5s
        # herein, I just take one sample with http req, in prod env, it will be other real task.
        # maybe can replace requests.get with other async module, but I just take one sample, because real task will be one common function

        print(f"{int(time())} exit from real task")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{int(time())} exit from real task")

async def wait_task():
    print(f"{int(time())} enter into wait task")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print(f"{int(time())} exit from wait task")
    
def test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task_set = set()
    task_set.add(loop.create_task(real_task()))
    task_set.add(loop.create_task(wait_task()))
    loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.wait(task_set)
    )
test()

root@ubuntu:~/cos/tmp# python thre.py
1723399962 : enter to real task
1723399967 exit from real task
1723399967 enter into wait task
1723399970 exit from wait task
root@ubuntu:~/cos/tmp# 

Excepted result:
1723399962 : enter to real task
1723399962 enter into wait task
1723399965 exit from wait task
1723399967 exit from real task


The issue is not that you have a 'common' function, but because you have blocking code inside of it. The requests module is not asynchronous thus it blocks the event loop, you have to use an asynchronous library (like aiohttp)

Yes, it is root cause, but is there one way to resolve this ?  for common task, maybe there is not async related lib to replace...

If your task wasn't blocking then you wouldn't experience this behavior, they would both run concurrently. The issue is because it's blocking, not because they are a "common" function.
